# Cannot resolve symbol in setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have a search button in my main activity "btnSearch", whenevr I press this button I want it to take me to a new activity "search", here's the Java code that I have for this:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        Button btnSearch= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(listener);

        View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Search.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };



    }
}
```

in the `btnSearch.setOnClickListener(listener);`. it gives me the error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'listner'.`

What should I do?

Comment: show the full file i mean including package name declaration and imports

Answer (score 3):

You declare the listener inside onCreate, which means it's only accessible after you initialize it. Move `btnSearch.setOnClickListener` after you create the listener, or move the listener declaration to the class level.

Alternatively, you can skip creating a variable entirely and just pass the listener directly:

```
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Search.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I just tried that, the error is gone but now the app crashes everytime I press the button, any suggestions?

Comment: Oww sorry I'm really new to this >.< found the error thanks, forgot to add the activity to the manifests. Thanks